# What is the size of these discrete function sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I'm interested in the set $F_n$ of functions $f:\{-1,1\}^n\to\{-1,1\}$ which can be represented as $x\mapsto\text{sign}(a\cdot x)$ for some $a\in\mathbf{R}^n$.  What is the size of $F_n$?  Is there some discrete encoding which is 'better' then to write down the complete lookup table?

My idea is to look at the number of connected components in $\mathbf{R}^n\setminus(\cup_x\{x\}^\bot)$, since if $a,a'$ represent different functions $f,f'$, say $f(y)\neq f'(y)$, then I can't go from $a$ to $a'$ without crossing the border $a\cdot y=0$.  But I still don't know how many such components there are.

[EDIT]  I just tried to [plot](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/xnkz65d2) the planes $\{x\}^\bot$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$ (w.l.o.g. $x_1=1$ since $\{x\}^\bot=\{-x\}^\bot$), there seem to be $14$ partitions and they seem to correspond to the faces and edges of the $[-1,1]^3$-cube.  But in even dimensions the picture needs to be different since the edges of the $[-1,1]^{2n}$-cube lie directly on the planes

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: My previous rough idea about orthants was completely off of the mark. I need to go rethink everything.

I have provided a link to a set of slides in the comments below, but I think I'm starting to get out of my depth. Someone who knows better than I should swoop in and save the day.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the input!  I just tried to [plot](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/xnkz65d2) the planes $\{x\}^\bot$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$ (w.l.o.g. $x_1=1$ since $\{x\}^\bot=\{-x\}^\bot$), but the resulting components don't look like orthants to me, some of them are enclosed by four planes but some only by three.  Or am I confused about this?

Comment: @fweth Oh man, what I wrote was truly a half baked idea if there ever was one. My very first line is obviously false; these are not spokes of a coordinate system as there are WAY too many of them, even after accounting for negatives. Sorry, back to the drawing board for me...

Comment: Don't worry, I'm glad you shared your intuition :)

Comment: @fweth I found an interesting set of slides about counting regions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that have been separated by hyperplanes. They even discuss what to do with hyperplanes that are not in general position, which is what we have here. It also looks a bit complicated. http://physics.csusb.edu/%7Eprenteln/papers/hyperintro.pdf